# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: flutter, gradle

How to solve this problem?

```
    [   +2 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
    [   +1 ms] Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
    [   +1 ms] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
    [   +1 ms]    > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10  
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +2 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +2 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [        ]      Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30        
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30        
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +2 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30        
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30        
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms]      Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
    [        ] * Try:
    [        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
    [        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [        ] * Exception is:
    [   +1 ms] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    [        ]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    [   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    [   +1 ms] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and
    jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10       
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +2 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)  
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +2 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30
    (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30)
    [   +1 ms] Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
    [   +1 ms]      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:65)
org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    [   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
    [   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    [   +2 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
    [        ]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    [   +1 ms]      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    [   +1 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    [   +3 ms]      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    [   +1 ms]      ... 5 more
    [   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [   +2 ms] BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

Comment: duplicate Kotlin version 1.8.10 and 1.5.30, you may check your build.gradle and gradle.properties files configuration